# Msiexec fails to run (command generated with NANT)

Tags: xml, nant, windows-installer

The following is used to generate an msiexec command with nant:

```
> "<exec program="msiexec"
> timeout="1800000" verbose="true">
>             <arg line="/i &quot;${server.msi}&quot;" />
>             <arg line="TARGETDIR=&quot;${server.target.path}&quot;"
> />
>             <arg line="INSTALLDIR=&quot;${server.target.path}&quot;"
> />
>             <arg line="ALLUSERS=1" />
>             <arg line="/quiet" />
>             <arg line="/log &quot;${path::combine(log.path,
> 'Installation.Server.log')}&quot;" />"

        </exec>
```

Th generated command is:
msiexec ( /i "S:\Work\Sources\Installation\Setup\LastBuild\WiseSetup Server.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\MyProgs\Server" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\MyProgs\Server" ALLUSERS=1; /quiet /log "C:\Projects\P3450\Environment\Logs\Installation.Server.log")

this command fails to execute when the /quiet (or /qn) is removed it runs successful. Otherwise it gives the error:
External Program Failed: msiexec (return code was 1619)

Note that of the "(" and ")" is removed and the /quiet is there it runs successful !

Comment: run following command from cmd window and see whether errorlevel is indeed 0
msiexec /i "S:\Work\Sources\Installation\Setup\LastBuild\WiseSetup Server.msi" TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files\MyProgs\Server" INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\MyProgs\Server" ALLUSERS=1 /quiet /log "C:\Projects\P3450\Environment\Logs\Installation.Server.log"

echo %errorlevel%

if error level is 0 then runt he same command from nant with the hardcoded arguments,
it must work as well. Then start replacing the arguments by variables and run nant after every change.

Answer (score 0):

Enable verbose logging using the /l*v command instead of just /log, open your msi log file ("Installation.Server.log"), and then search for "return value 3" to jump directly to where the setup installer failed.  You can also use the windows installer verbose setup log analyzer to analyze the log file if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/229683), error code 1619 indicates that the package cannot be opened.

What this usually means, is that something else has a lock open on the file *at the time nant is trying to execute msiexec* - a common problem if anyone else has Windows Explorer open to `S:\Work\Sources\Installation\Setup\LastBuild\WiseSetup Server.msi` in your example, it's probably just trying to generate a thumbnail.

Stick a timeout/wait in before executing this nant task and see if that helps, if so then something else has a hold on your file - this would also explain why it succeeds when you run the command manually, the lock has been released by that time.